# What is faster? Two comparisons or one comparison with one logical check?

Tags: javascript, performance

Ok, while I was nesting some validation if, I've come into something about performance.

Let's suppose I'm validating a ticket to a show, I can do something like this:

```
var validateVipTicket = function (ticketInfo) {
  if (ticketInfo.isPaid) {
    if (ticketInfo.isOver16) {
      if (ticketInfo.isVip) {
        return true;
      } else return 'Not Vip';
    } else return 'Not old enought';
  } else return 'Need to pay first';
};
```

And call it like this `validateVipTicket({isPaid: true, isOver16: true, isVip: true});`

**BUT**
let's suppose that does not matter to specify what error happened, I just want a true or false, then, what approach would be faster?

```
if (ticketInfo.isPaid) {
  if (ticketInfo.isOver16) {
```

**OR**

```
if (ticketInfo.isPaid && ticketInfo.isOver16) {
```

On the **first case**, the first property will be checked and, when it finishes, the second property will be checked. On the **second case**, the first property will be checked, the second property will be checked and, them, both properties will be compared against each other. Is this right? Am I missing something? Which is faster and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no difference:

```
if ( a && b )
```

is the same as

```
if ( a )
   if ( b )
```

In the case of `a && b`, as soon as `a` is found false, then it does not matter what `b` is.

What happens at the CPU instruction level in both cases is:

```
cmp   [a], 0    ; a == 0?  (it does this by calculating a - 0)
jz    false1    ; jump if result is zero
; a is true
cmp   [b], 0
jz    false2
; both a and b are true
```

Whether 3 different messages are returned, or just 1, could make a difference in speed, depending on how it is compiled. In this example, it makes no difference:

```
false1:  return "not a!";
false2:  return "not b!";

just_false: return false;
```

But here, an extra jump/goto is involved:

```
false1:  result = "not a!"; goto done;
false2:  result = "not b!"; // goto done optimized away
done: return result;
```

Comment: "What happens at the CPU". Good point. Low level is a good place to explain.

Answer (score 2):

> On the second case, the first property will be checked, the second
>   property will be checked and, them, both properties will be compared
>   against each other. Is this right?

No, that's actually not right. The `&&` operator does a [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation), which means that the second operand is never evaluated if the first operand evaluates to `false`.

That makes the two approaches exactly equivalent (even if there were any side effects of evaluating the oparands). As they do exactly the same amount of work in the same way, you can expect the performance to be very similar. It's even likely that the approaches end up generating the same executable code in the end.

Answer (score 1):

The 2 statements are equivalent in terms of performance. In both cases the second check (`ticketInfo.isOver16`) will be evaluated only if the first check (`ticketInfo.isPaid`) has returned true. Both statements are absolutely the same in terms of speed. So you should prefer the one that's more readable to you.

Answer (score 1):

The performance in modern JS Engines such as V8 would be the same. Although there is always the chance that a crappy interpreter performs one better than the other but with modern browsers and JIT compilers such as V8 you should get the same results.

Proof of concept:
http://jsperf.com/nested-conditionals-vs-inline